# Error while parsing logs with spilp

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse some logs with spilp and I get the following error at end=" ":

[Spilp](http://code.google.com/p/spilp/)

```
File "spilp.py", line 346
    print("\n\nENTERING FOLDER: ", end=" ")
```

I have installed python 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04, but when I check the version it shows as python 2.7. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Python 3 is a separate program. Try invoking your script with:

```
$ python3 "splilp.py"
```

You can check the version of python 3 using:

```
$ python3 --version
```

Which is totally different from:

```
$ python --version
```

Basically the interpreter (python 2) expects syntax like:

```
>>> print "string here"
```

rather than

```
>>> print("string here")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But it gives the following Error? No command 'paython3' found, did you mean:
 Command 'python3' from package 'python3-minimal' (main)
paython3: command not found